# Tomcat Clustering

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, load-balancing

I have made Tomcat clustering using Apache HTTPD and Two Tomcat 7.0.xx with MOD_JK. I do not use session sharing as my old application is not supporting Serializeable. But Load Balancer is working fine with ratio 1:1.

When I stop first tomcat. any further request came to second one and it also working fine.

When I stop application on first tomcat(tomcat is running for other applications) then it cannot shift load to second tomcat. Half request does not entertains and 500 error in half request. Any further solution ??? ..

Comment: I am using CentOS

Comment: An error 500 will be accompanied by an exception and stack trace in a Tomcat log file. WIthout that information your question is not complete.

Comment: Could you please include the JK configurations from your httpd.conf?

Answer (score 1):

mod_jk loadbalances between servers, not applications.  Therefore, if a tomcat is up and the application inside it is down, you will have errors 50% of the time.